# when I am executing "celery -A myproj worker" in Django-celery getting WindowsError: [Error 87]

Tags: python-2.7, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I am trying to configure a scheduled task using **Django** **Celery** using **RabbitMQ**. After creating object for celery class and some tasks in my project directory, when I am trying to configure Worker using following command

"**celery -A myproj worker**" I am getting the following traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\murugk7\envs\celery_test\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\worker.py", line 203, in sta
rt
    self.blueprint.start(self)
  File "c:\users\murugk7\envs\celery_test\lib\site-packages\celery\bootsteps.py", line 119, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "c:\users\murugk7\envs\celery_test\lib\site-packages\celery\bootsteps.py", line 370, in start
    return self.obj.start()
  File "c:\users\murugk7\envs\celery_test\lib\site-packages\celery\concurrency\base.py", line 131, in
start
    self.on_start()
  File "c:\users\murugk7\envs\celery_test\lib\site-packages\celery\concurrency\prefork.py", line 112,
in on_start
    **self.options)
  File "c:\users\murugk7\envs\celery_test\lib\site-packages\billiard\pool.py", line 1008, in __init__
    self._create_worker_process(i)
  File "c:\users\murugk7\envs\celery_test\lib\site-packages\billiard\pool.py", line 1117, in _create_w
orker_process
    w.start()
  File "c:\users\murugk7\envs\celery_test\lib\site-packages\billiard\process.py", line 122, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "c:\users\murugk7\envs\celery_test\lib\site-packages\billiard\context.py", line 383, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "c:\users\murugk7\envs\celery_test\lib\site-packages\billiard\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 64, i
n __init__
    _winapi.CloseHandle(ht)
TypeError: must be integer<k>, not _subprocess_handle

(celery_test) C:\kavin\Assigner\assigner>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\murugk7\envs\celery_test\lib\site-packages\billiard\spawn.py", line 159, in spawn_mai
n
    new_handle = steal_handle(parent_pid, pipe_handle)
  File "c:\users\murugk7\envs\celery_test\lib\site-packages\billiard\reduction.py", line 121, in steal
_handle
    _winapi.PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE, False, source_pid)
WindowsError: [Error 87] The parameter is incorrect
```

In settings.py it has

```
app = Celery('assigner',
             broker='amqp://myuser:mypass@localhost/my_Vhost',
             backend='rpc://',
             include=['assigner.tasks'])
```

In tasks.py, it has

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from assigner.celery import app
import time


@app.task
def longtime_add(x, y):
    print 'long time task begins'
    # sleep 5 seconds
    time.sleep(5)
    print 'long time task finished'
    return x + y
```

I am using **Django-1.8**, **celery-4.0**, **amqp=2.1.1** 
where **myporj** is my Django project name

Please help me in solving this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found this error, too.

And the reason is quite simple. celery 4.x just does not support windows.

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html#does-celery-support-windows.

So, I guess you need try the earlier version or switch to linux systems.